# Can Swift UI tab-focus between TextFields and Pickers?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, focus, picker

I have a Swift UI Form (on Mac OS, Xcode 13), and it has some TextFields, and in the middle a Picker with two Text options. Currently, the user can press the tab key to move focus between the TextFields just fine, but it skips over the picker options. I've tried adding `.focusable()` to the Picker and to the Text options inside the picker to no effect. I would like for the user to be able to press tab to select the Picker group, and use the arrow keys to move between the options, and press tab again to move onto the next TextField.

Here's a quick example of what my code looks like (shortened to what's relevant)

```
Form
{
    TextField("First text field", text: $first)
        .focused($focused, equals: .first)

    Picker("Picker", selection: $pickerSelection)
    {
        Text("Option 1").tag(true as Bool?)
        Text("Option 2").tag(false as Bool?)
    }

    TextField("Second text field", text: $second)
        .focused($focused, equals: .second)
}
```

Comment: Sadly focus does not work for Pickers in SwiftUI

Comment: Damn, that's unfortunate. I guess I'll submit a suggestion on feedback assistant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by enabling "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Once this setting was enabled my Picker began acting as a tab stop. The unfortunate part of this is that it would have to be enabled on every user's device for it to take effect; however, I don't see any way around it.

[Mac Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXf3w.png)

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 14, the setting's location and name changed:
[image: macOS System Settings]